# IndexError: tuple index out of range (Frappe/Erpnext)

Tags: python-3.x, erpnext, frappe

I am trying to modify code below but I am getting a "tuple index out of range" error.

```
price_list_name = frappe.db.sql("""select name
                from `tabItem Price` a 
                where a.item_code = %s and a.selling = 1 
                and a.uom = %s
                and a.creation = (select max(b.creation) from `tabItem Price` b 
                where a.item_code = b.item_code and b.selling = 1)""",(d.item_code, d.uom))
        frappe.log(price_list_name)
        name = price_list_name[0][0]
        price_doc = frappe.get_doc("Item Price",name)
```

This is the error message:

```
File "/home/frappe/erpnext/apps/xlevel_sales/xlevel_sales/custom_method.py", line 27, in update_item_price_list
name = price_list_name[0][0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: First check what is the value you are getting in `price_list_name`. The error is due to `price_list_name[0][0]`. So, you are probably not getting any value in it for that condition.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `price_list_name` does not return any value, add `if` condition to avoid the error.

```
if price_list_name:
        name = price_list_name[0][0]
        price_doc = frappe.get_doc("Item Price",name)
```